# Laravel - passing route parameter to blade

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.6, with the default make:auth mechanism.

In the routes/web.php, I would like to add a language middleware as follow:-

```
Route::prefix('{lang}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
});
```

Now I wish to apply this in blade:-

```
<a href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
```

But debugger just say:-

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: password.request] [URI: {lang}/password/reset].
```

I believe the blade cannot not get the {lang} from route. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="{{ url('en') }}/password/reset">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a prefix in the route it means that it is going to be included in the route, so when you say

```
Route::prefix('{lang}')->group(function () {
Route::get('password/reset' .......
Route::get('foo/bar' .......
```

it means the route will be like this "http://yourwebsite.com/{lang}/password/reset"
"http://yourwebsite.com/{lang}/foo/bar"

so each time you pass any route that falls in that group will need to have a variable called $lang so the link can be initialized.

so in your case

```
<a href="{{ route('password.request', ['lang' => 'en']) }}"> //you can change en to your preferred language.
```

if you want to [add a middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware) to specific route or route group, it is passed in this way

```
Route::get('/', function () {
//
})->middleware('first', 'second');
```

or

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['first']], function () {
//
});
```

if you want to create another language, you can check the below links:

[Laravel localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization)

[spatie/laravel-translation-loader](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translation-loader)

Comment: this method is working. Besides, in the case of {{ route('password.request', ['lang' => 'en']) }}, if I wish to use {{ route('password.request') }}, and modify the route() function to include ['lang' => 'en'] automatically, is it possible???

Comment: if you would explain further, whether you want to change all the language to en or are you planning to use another language, I might be a better help